# Giant file full of event handlers! How to organize a large jQuery file in an AJAX web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, namespaces, organization

I've made an AJAX-heavy web application and included jQuery as a library to help facilitate DOM manipulation and AJAX requests, etc. Here is the problem:

**My JavaScript file is a giant collection of event handlers!!!!!**

I'm being serious, probably 30+ event handlers and I don't even want to count. It basically looks like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#element', function() {
    $.get('url' + id, function(data) {
        //do stuff
    });
});

$('div.selector').hover(function() {
    //do stuff
}, function() {
    //undo stuff
});

$(document).on('submit', 'form#form-selector', function() {
    $.post('/url', $('form#form-selector').serializeObject(), function(data) {
        //do stuff
    });
});
```

ad infinitum with a few functions and prototype stuff in there to get the commonly-repeated functionality I need. It works just fine, but I know this cannot be right and it seems really ugly. On top of that, it seems bad to wrap most of it in a `$(document).ready()` and it's miserable to try to sort through the code and find the section I want without using my text editor's find functionality.

How do you organize a large project like this? I am aware of stuff like Backbone.js, but I wasn't sure if this is the intended use-case and I am already using a server-side framework in PHP to do templating and other things, so I don't need a full-blown JavaScript framework. Are namespaces the answer/are they really going to help anything? I've done some research and didn't find much besides namespaces... much to my surprise/frustration.

**Help me escape the event handlers of doom!**

Comment: More info: I'm using Laravel and already have the backend set to handle all the requests/pass back data.. it seems like my JS file is just a place to fire AJAX requests and then manipulate the DOM in response. There must be a better way...

Answer (score 0):

You could group elements which trigger the same event into a group. And perform operations in a single event function in the following way:

```
$("#b1,#b2").on("click",function(event){
 var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
 switch(target.id)
 {
    case "b1":
      alert("Im One");
    break;
    case "b2":
      alert("Im Two");
    break;
 }});
```

Sample code here : http://codepen.io/tejzpr/pen/pvMxMw/